# How to properly perform a one to many mapping in ASP.NET with Entity Framework in its entirety

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Currently I am working with ASP.NET and Entity Framework. I am trying to set up users which will have a one-to-many relationship with notes (one user, many notes).

I believe the fields are correct on both classes for setting up the relationship however when I try to work with setting the user on the note I am being told by swagger that the user field for notes must not be null. With this adding the note to the user does not work. I am quite new to this so any help is appreciated thank you.

The api method I am referring to:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("noteAdd/{userId:Guid}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddNoteToUser([FromRoute] Guid userId, [FromBody] Note note)  //The Note constructor is getting called from here which is strange
{
    //Uncreachable since constructor gets called before this
    /*
     *  This api was used to test other possibilities, original one still exists
     *  
     * 
     */

var user = await notesDbContext.Users.SingleAsync(u => u.Id ==userId); //get the user from the database
        notesDbContext.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(user);

}
```

The Note constructor:

```
public Note(User user, string title, string description)  //Constructor for Note 
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(user, nameof(user)); //Caught here right after calling the api method
    ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(title, nameof(title));
    ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(description, nameof(description));

    User = user;
    Title = title;
    Description = description;
    IsVisible = true;
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();

}
```

Even without calling the constructor within the body of the api method
it goes straight to the constructor after seeing [FromBody] Note note within the function parameters.

Comment: Please don't refer to external links if they're a prerequisite to understanding the question and also post code as text, not as images.

Comment: Please explain what "does not work" means. That said, remove `user` from the constructor. It's redundant and error-prone. The note will be added to the user by the statement `user.Notes.Add(myNote)`

Comment: You're not making the question any more clear. "original one still exists". Where? *That* said, use a DTO object to transfer note data and create the real Note only in the action method. Now the middleware constructs a Note when deserializing the request. When there's no default constructor, that will fail.

Answer (score 0):

C#'s null-able warnings can be a bit of a nuisance when it comes to Entity Framework and that EF will generally be responsible for ensuring that references are initialized and present. When it comes to collection navigation properties, you should always initialize these to a new `List` or `HashSet` so that they are ready to received data when constructing new instances. So for User.Notes:

```
public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; protected set; } = new List<Note>();
```

... rather than using a null-able List to keep the compiler happy. Note that the setter is protected. Entity collections should never be re-set to a new collection as this will muck up EF's change tracker.  This ensures the collection is always ready to go. For singular navigation properties such as Note.User, do *not* initialize these. If the navigation property is not null-able in the database, do not declare it as null-able in the entity either, add it to the public constructor. (see below)

There are two approaches when adding a child to a parent:

```
var user = context.Users
    .Single(u => u.Id == userId);
var note = new Note(user, /* add any/all required fields */);

// Option 1:

user.Notes.Add(note);

// or Option 2:

// context.Notes.Add(note);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Option 1 can be used where Notes do not otherwise need a `DbSet` exposed on the `DbContext` and are only accessed through their User.Notes collection.

As a general rule with EF entities there should be a public constructor that accepts all required values and navigation properties (non-null-able), then you can have a protected default constructor set up for EF to use behind the scenes when it goes to load entities from the database. So for instance if a Note requires a User and a Message text property to be valid:

```
public Note(User user, string message)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(user, nameof(user));
    ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(message, nameof(message));

    User = user;
    Message = message;
}

 #pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor used by EF.
    /// </summary>
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    protected Note()
    { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
```

This keeps the compiler "happy". Anything optional in the entity would be left null-able, where anything required should be added via the constructor.

When it comes to initializing relationships you can use either the navigation property (Note.User) or a FK property. (Note.UserId) If you set both, the navigation property takes precedence. Typically I recommend using one or the other, not both. So for instance when using navigation properties, using a shadow property for the FK. (No Note.UserId exposed as a property) By setting navigation properties it does incur a cost of a round trip to the DB, but you often need information from the entity anyways and if there is an issue pulling the data, the exception occurs at the point the data is read rather than on `SaveChanges`. Using the FK is better for cases where performance is crucial, or dealing with things like lookup tables where values don't change.

**Update**: The error you are still getting is due to MVC trying to use the parameterized constructor when deserializing a Note data from the data provided from the view when calling the action. That data does not contain a user so the constructor guards are getting triggered. Ultimately entities are meant to serve as data domain, not transport containers for a view.For MVC to properly deserialize an entity, it would need to receive all properties and details from all related navigation properties to try and put one back together. In most cases this complete set of data is not coming back.

Instead, the controllers should pass, and receive a simple view model representing the data values that the view actually needs. This will often look a lot like an entity, but will ignore, or simplify related data that can be passed back to fetch or build an entity within the controller action.

For instance a NoteViewModel:

```
public class NoteViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; } = true;
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
}
```

If you have a controller action to view a Note, you can use `Select` to project that note into a NoteViewModel to serve as the model for the view instead of passing an entire Note entity, which will want to serialize the entire User entity and any other entities related to Note and etc. down the chain.

```
var noteVM = notesDbContext.Notes
    .Where(n => n.Id == noteId)
    .Select(n => new NoteViewModel
    {
        Id = n.Id,
        Title = n.Title,
        Description = n.Description,
        IsVisible = n.IsVisible,
        UserId = n.User.Id,
        UserName = n.User.Name
   }).Single();
   return View(noteVM);
```

Or passing a new NoteViewModel instance in the case of a CreateNote action, etc. For your action to submit a note creation, the submit will populate or send the FormData as the NoteViewModel rather than a Note entity. This is a simpler, lighter representation of a note that won't be confused for a domain entity and doesn't have, or need the same scrutiny, it is just view data. The controller basically does what your code already does, fetch the user provided the UserId (if present), verify that all values on the ViewModel are correct, then create a new Note entity.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddNoteToUser([FromRoute] Guid userId, [FromBody] NoteViewModel note)  
{
    // ... Essentially the exact code you have just adjust to use properties provided in the simpler view model (i.e. note.UserId) to find the user etc.
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the help and sorry for the late reply. The issue is as of right now that when sending user over to the constructor for a note it is null? and for some reason it bypasses the if statement I have checking if it is null also. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Can you update your question with the updated code, just copy and paste the methods into the question and use the code block formatting (button with "{ }" in the text editor) which will make it easier to see what is going on.

Comment: does this  edit help see at all? this is my first question so my apologies if it is difficult to understand. Appreciate the help though. also when using breakpoints for some reason user is null?

Comment: Ok, so in your updated example which line fails, and what is the full exception message? I don't see anything wrong with your example provide your User.Notes collection property is initialized to a `= new List<Note>();` The only way the user reference could be null is if the call to `SingleAsync` actually failed, and that would have caused an exception on that line. If the Null reference was on the Notes collection, you need to initialize it within the User entity definition as per above and the first code example in my answer.

Comment: So it gets caught in the nullexception within the note constructor. I removed the constructor from the api call and it turns out that before the rest of the body gets executed the api method actually calls the Note constructor from within the parameter. Ill update the question so you can see what I mean

Comment: AH, yes. ok that will be a problem with the deserialization of the data coming from the browser in the request body. Have you added that protected default constructor in my example above? I put the `#pragma warning....` wrapper to keep .Net content around null reference warnings on that default constructor. This way, MVC and EF can use that constructor when building a note. That may not work for the MVC deserialization though. I do not recommend using the entity class as a transport DTO between controller and view, the view should be bound, and pass back dedicated simple view model DTO classes

Comment: I have updated the answer to demonstrate a simple NoteViewModel class and how it is used.